# How do I run sass in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sass

How do I call a sass function from inside a ruby file?

The following line works in the command prompt:

```
sass C:\Users\..etc..\main.scss
```

I need to put this into a Ruby file. So I wrote as below in a Ruby file:

```
require 'sass'

$arg1 = 'C:/Users/dmoores/Desktop/testst/main.scss'
sass $arg1
```

But it complains with the following:

```
undefined method `sass' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the options as you need, then use `Sass::Engine#render`.

```
require "sass"
options = {
  cache: true,
  syntax: :sass,
  style: :compressed,
  filename: original_file_name,
  ...
}
render = Sass::Engine.new(File.read(original_file_name), options).render
File.write(output_file_name, render)
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work while there are @imports in the original_file_name ... "File to import not found or unreadable" while "system 'sass _sass/styles.scss styles.css'" builds just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This documentation should help:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

If you've already installed the Sass gem, you can run it from the Command Line.
To use Sass in your ruby script, you need to make a Sass object and then use the functions associated with it.

Comment: I always thought it was good to look at the documentation, since it is actually pretty clear in there. @sawa types it out, but its pretty much is on that page I linked.

Comment: I had looked at that documentation, but thought those examples were purely for Rails. I guess this stuff will become clearer to me with more time on Ruby. Thanks for reading!